# override Android systemapi

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to override the `com.android.incallui` classes like [StatusBarNotifier](http://www.androidcodesearch.com/source/packages/apps/InCallUI/src/com/android/incallui/StatusBarNotifier.java)?

Reason is that I want to change the `incall ui` and the top level notification when there is a fullscreen activity while someone is calling.